# Why my AJAX get request not always returns correct value, RoR, CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, get

My CoffeeScript file looks like this:

```
updateDot = (iDraggingID, newX, newY) ->
  $.ajax "/dots/#{iDraggingID}",
    type:'PUT'
    dataType:'json'
    data: {dot: {position_x: "#{newX}", position_y: "#{newY}"}}

refreshDot = (id) ->
  $.ajax
    url: "/dots/#{id}"
    type: "GET"
    dataType: 'json'
    success: (data) ->
    moveDot data['position_x'], data['position_y'], "dot#{id}"

handleDragStop = (event, ui) ->
  newX = parseInt( ui.offset.left );
  newY = parseInt( ui.offset.top );
  sDraggingID = $(this).attr 'id'
  iDraggingID = sDraggingID.match(/\d+/)[0]
  updateDot iDraggingID, newX, newY
  refreshDot(iDraggingID)

moveDot = (x, y, id) ->
  document.getElementById(id).style.left = "#{x}px";
  document.getElementById(id).style.top = "#{y}px";

moveDots = (x) ->
  moveDot(i['position_x'], i['position_y'], "dot#{i['id']}") for i in x

jQuery -> # starts all of this
  moveDots gon.dots #basically returns JSON with all elements from database
  $('.dot').draggable
    containment: '#parent',
    cursor: 'move',
    stop: handleDragStop #when dragging an element is done trigger this
```

And my Controller:

```
class DotsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @dots = Dot.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :nothing => true }
    format.json { render :json => @dots, :status => :ok }
  end
end

def show
  @dot = Dot.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  { render :nothing => true }
    format.json  { render :json => @dot, :status => :ok }
  end
end

def create
  @dot = Dot.new(dot_params)
  @dot.save
end

def update
  @dot = Dot.find(params[:id])
  @dot.update_attributes(dot_edit_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  { render :nothing => true }
    format.json  { render :json => @dot, :status => :ok}
  end
end

def destroy
   @dot = Dot.(params[:id])
   @dot.destroy
end
private
  def dot_params
    params.require(:dot).permit(:name, :position_x, :position_y)
  end

  def dot_edit_params
    params.require(:dot).permit(:position_x, :position_y)
  end
end
```

Why sometimes when I call refreshDot from CoffeeScript Im getting correct value of position_x and position_y … and sometimes Im getting the old  values??? It seems to be 70:30 good:bad returns.

It's becouse GET method is called (somehow) before the PUT method actually ends .. or what? Im so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of using asynchronous (AJAX) requests means that the second might get done before the first. If there are dependencies, consider using callbacks.

Like this:

```
updateDot = (iDraggingID, newX, newY) ->
  $.ajax "/dots/#{iDraggingID}",
    type:'PUT'
    dataType:'json'
    data: {dot: {position_x: "#{newX}", position_y: "#{newY}"}}
    success: (data) ->
      moveDot data['position_x'], data['position_y'], "dot#{id}"

handleDragStop = (event, ui) ->
  newX = parseInt( ui.offset.left );
  newY = parseInt( ui.offset.top );
  sDraggingID = $(this).attr 'id'
  iDraggingID = sDraggingID.match(/\d+/)[0]
  updateDot iDraggingID, newX, newY
```

Comment: I've trying to do smth like this (with success callback: )

`updateDot = (iDraggingID, newX, newY) ->
  $.ajax "/dots/#{iDraggingID}",
    type:'PUT'
    dataType:'json'
    data: {dot: {position_x: "#{newX}", position_y: "#{newY}"}}
    success: refreshDot iDraggingID`

but it's no difference. Is there any other method except "success" .. like "when the things done:" callback? ;>

Comment: You would also need to also remove the `refreshDot` call in your `handleDragStop` function.

Comment: well guys .. I've just done all of this and it's even worse .. now it's always returns bad result. Is there any method I can use to delay get just to give some more time to update? It would be fancy enough?

Comment: Try it without the refreshDot fucntion (I updated my example code) ...also, check your indentation in the CoffeeScript. The moveDot call needs to be indented under the success callback.

Comment: Mayby its becouse I'm calling ajax request in callback of other ajax request? ;>>>>

Comment: No, you can call new requests in callbacks of other requests. That's not a problem ...just as long as everything is in the right order.

Comment: I dont want to do this. Becouse i heve some validation in my Model. When I'm making UPDATE - in some conditions it will rollback and my model wont be save in my newX and newY positions … and becouse of this .. i want to ask server one more time if my dot was moved succesfuly or not. Thats why i have second ajax request one after another.

Comment: The data from `@dot` could be returned even is it does't save because of validation issues. Just return the unchanged data. Reading the show and update methods in Ruby, it will do the same thing.

Does it work with the example I have?

Comment: Yes! The reason why my code didn't work is that i didn't call `(data) ->` before moveDot in success: callback .. I assumed it didnt wait for data then to be returned but just go ahead and pull data just before update. Thanks a lot Karl!